# Rewrite 'http' into 'https' in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, drupal-7, wampserver

how to use `https://localhost/` instead of `http://localhost/` ?

I am using WAMPSERVER 2.

Is there any way to rewrite http into https...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: thnk u. do u know any article about installing ssl in apache(WAMP) in win xp...? @anubhava

Comment: No I don't know but I am sure you can find something on Google search.